# How to deal with json data in python?

Tags: python, json, google-custom-search

```python
# This code searches the query from googlecustomsearch api and returns data in json format   
import pprint
import json

from googleapiclient.discovery import build


my_api_key = "**************************************"
my_cse_id = "*************************************"

def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']


results = google_search(
    'Roshan Patel', my_api_key, my_cse_id, num=10)
for result in results:
    pprint.pprint(result)
    result_dict = json.loads(result)
    print result_dict['formattedUrl']
```

This is the output i am getting:
[image]

I want to get only the url parts for eg :u'formattedUrl' and store it in a list , how to do it?

New error

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-38-eb898c8de239>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/abc/untitled9.py', wdir='C:/Users/abc')

  File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/abc/untitled9.py", line 28, in <module>
    result_dict = json.loads(result)

  File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda2\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "C:\Users\abc\Anaconda2\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: I am building a mini contactibility search enigne.

Comment: It looks like `result` is not JSON, but an actual Python dictionary, so just `print result[u'formattedUrl']`.

Comment: Thanks  Mark , it was actually a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need first convert the results to a Python object, like a dict, to do that uses the json module:

```
result_dict = json.loads(result)
```

Now you can filter your dict:

```
result_dict['formattedUrl']
```

Comment: I am getting this error .TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 1):

`result` is not JSON, but an actual Python dictionary, so just:

```
print result[u'formattedUrl']
```